# WatiN displaying the wrong URL

Tags: c#, watin

I'm working with WatiN for about two days since I am trying to implement a SSSO and I just came across a problem (never worked with website automation before).

```
using(var ie = new IE("http://www.example.org")){
    Console.WriteLine(ie.Uri.ToString()) // Correct URL example.org
    ie.GoTo("http://www.example2.org"))
    Console.WriteLine(ie.Uri.ToString()) // Still example.org
    }
```

May someone explain this to me? I handle a Windows-Dialog on example.org, then I click on a href, which leads me to example2.org where I am supposed to fill some textfields but the textfields were not found and I got an exception.

```
var ie = new IE("http://www.example.org");
Console.WriteLine(ie.Uri.ToString()); // example.org
ie.Close();
ie = new IE("http://www.example2.org");
Console.WriteLine(ie.Uri.ToString()); // example2.org
```

Second one works of course, but why exactly is the first solution not working? Basically still the old website is being referenced even though it is not opened any longer.

Answer (score 0):

I use Watir and I don't really know C# but since no one else has answered...

In the first example you are defining the 'ie' variable as `IE("http://www.example.org")`
and then on line 3 you are simply referencing the original 'ie' variable.
So the 'ie' variable still has the value that you gave it in line 1.

In the second example you define 'ie' to equal the first url.
Then on line 3 you are changing the value of 'ie' to the 2nd url.

The console is not printing out the url that your browser is currently on, it is simply printing out the value of 'ie' as you have set it in the code because you are including the uri as part of the value of 'ie'.

If you are gonna 'set' the url in the 'var' you might want to name it something more descriptive to its value, like below:

```
var ie_example = new IE("http://www.example.org");
Console.WriteLine(ie_example.LocationURL.ToString()); // example.org
ie_example.Close();
var ie_example2 = new IE("http://www.example2.org");
Console.WriteLine(ie_example2.LocationURL.ToString()); // example2.org
```